Can Agents Parse HTML in their output for digital experience chat bot?
We're working in prompt builder and making outputs that are in abridged HTML format (to be compatible with Salesforce's Agent) to write into records in Salesforce long rich text area fields.
We are using HTML formatted text output for a prompt that writes to a long rich text area field (putting in formatting etc. using its RTF capabilities) in the back end, but in the near future, we will also need the same information to display in the agent in a digital experience site without showing the HTML tags and elements and displaying them as text. We have not yet activated the agent on Digital Experience, but are trying to plan ahead. Currently from our testing, it appears to us that when displaying prompt output in Digital Experience, it displays as plain text output, and in so doing, has the undesired effect of outputting all HTML tags, elements, etc. in the output.
Can an agent be taught or a prompt be crafted that will enable the agent to parse (or ignore) the HTML prior to output directly into Digital Experience and use it to format the output, or will we need to use separate prompts for each use case? Alternatively, is there another option that we haven't considered to handle this issue without having to have two copies of each prompt, one for in-community/digital experience site and one for writing to a record on the back end? We're using flow to trigger the prompt, and we're not currently aware of a way to let the prompt know whether its outcome is going to be viewed in the chat bot in Digital Experience directly, or as the contents of a record to which the output has previously been written.

The Service Agents does not support this currently. This feature is in roadmap though but today it is not possible.
